# How do you work with vectors and perform discrete calculations on rows in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I'm trying to work with the polynom library, specifically the functions polynomial(returns a vector representing a polynomial equation) and solve(expects a vector representing a polynomial equation and return a vector of roots)

In a dataset i'm working with, there is a trending increase in a value such that the current value is typically x times the previous value, as time goes on x can be influenced so it can fluctuate. I'm trying to graph the trend over time by calculating what x would be for a 7 day window. An example might be easier to explain:

```
     x   total(cumsum(x))
     0       0
    99      99
   187     286
   405     691
   801    1492
  1623    3115
  3214    6329
  6400   12729
 12765   25494
 25634   51128
 51222  102350
102201  204551
```

The data here show an increase in x by a factor of approx 2 each day. I'm looking to graph how this factor changes each day giving with a window of 7 days to calculate the factor. so if the factor is y, i know that the total for any 7 day window windows can be calculated as x + xy^1 + xy^2 + xy^3 + xy^4 + xy^5 + xy^6 = t, where x is the initial x value in that window and t is the difference in totals between the last day of the window and the day prior to the first day of the window.

To assist i add the following columns with dplyr library:

```
data$diff <- data$total - lag(data$total, n=7L, default = 0)
data$init <- lag(data$x, n=6L, default = 0)
```

The first 6 days will be missing either the delta or initial vales so i can ignore them:

```
data <- data[data$init > 0, ]
```

I'm now left with the following data

```
     x  total init   diff
  6400  12729   99  12729
 12765  25494  187  25395
 25634  51128  405  50842
 51222 102350  801 101659
102201 204551 1623 203059
```

I have written this simple function to calculate the trend:

```
calcTrend <- function (initValue, difference) {
    p <- polynomial(c(initValue - difference, initValue, initValue, initValue, initValue, initValue, initValue))
    roots <- solve(p)
    trend <- Re(roots[Im(roots) == 0 & Re(roots) > 0]) # discard imaginary and negative results. the remaining value is the sole value we need

    return(trend)
}
```

Now if I try this with simple test values to works as expected:

```
calcTrend(100, 12700)
# returns the value 2 as expected
```

However, when I run it for the data with:

```
data$trend <- calcTrend(data$init, data$diff)
```

I get the single incorrect same value (1.148392) returned for all rows. It would seem in the function the value p is given the results for all rows and solve(p) then calculates as if its one polynomial equation rather than 5 different equations. How should I write this so that it correctly calculates for each individual row?

Comment: (1) Is `getTrend` a typo of `calcTrend`? (2) Assuming your function needs a single argument at a time, consider `mapply(calcTrend, data$init, data$diff)` to run the function over each row of the frame's two columns' values.

Comment: (1) yes it is, I've edited the question to fix this. (2) this is perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant `calcTrend` one can try `mapply`

```
mapply(calcTrend,initValue=data$init,difference=data$diff)
```

> Output

```
[1] 2.004883 2.026633 1.995416 1.999735 1.994085
```